# Check if current date / time match with defined timespans

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, timestamp

Hi I've got follow code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.currentOption;

  $scope.setCurrentTimespan = function() {
    //CODE HERE
  };
  
  $scope.timespanList = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'morning',
    startDate: '19.09.2016 06:00',
    endDate: '19.09.2016 11:59'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'noon',
    startDate: '19.09.2016 12:00',
    endDate: '19.09.2016 13:29'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'afternoon',
    startDate: '19.09.2016 13:30',
    endDate: '19.09.2016 18:29'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'evening',
    startDate: '19.09.2016 18:30',
    endDate: '19.09.2016 23:59'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'night',
    startDate: '20.09.2016 00:00',
    endDate: '20.09.2016 05:59'
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <select ng-options="option as option.name for option in timespanList" ng-model="currentOption"></select>
</div>
```

I've got from the backend a object with items for my `select`. In this list there are some timespans like morning, noon, afternoon etc. This timespans have a startDate and an endDate, which also comes from the backend. For example, the timespan "morning" has follow startDate/endDate: [todays date] 06:00 / [todays date] 11:59. So what I want to do is, when I load the list and fill the `select` with `ng-options`, I would like to select the item from the list, which matches with the current timestamp. So I have to get the current date and time for example: 19.09.2016 09:45 and than search in the list the item which is defined for this timestamp and select it in the list. So I have to check the startDate/endDate with the current date / time. This should happen when the list was loaded.

So the result for my local time (19.09.2016 09:45) at this moment would be **morning**.

Has someone an idea how to do this? I didn't find any answers which can help me...Thanks

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION:**

I've found a perfect way to solve this problem: I found `moment.js`, which solves my requirements. After including it into my web app I start to use the queries and functions from `moment.js` to solve my problem. It works like this:

Get current timestamp (day, month, year, hour and minutes):

```
let currentTimestamp = moment(); //for example 19.09.2016 11:30
```

Than I loop throught my array with the timespans and parse the startDate/endDate with the `moment.js` to my required `format` `DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm` and then I can use the `moment.js` `query` `isBetween()` to check, if my currentTimestamp is between the startDate/endDate of each item like this:

```
this.timespanList.forEach(function(item) {
    let startDate = moment(item.startDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'); // for example 19.09.2016 06:00
    let endDate= moment(item.endDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'); // for example 19.09.2016 11:59

    if(moment(currentTimestamp).isBetween(startDate, endDate)) {
        $scope.currentOption = item;
    }
});
```

So if the condition of the looped item is true, I can set the right option in my list. Here are some links of `moment.js` which describe, how to use it correcty - it's awesome!

moment.js docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/

moment.js parsing: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

moment.js queries: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

I hope this is usefull! An alternative solution from the answers which also would work is marked as correct. Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom filter to achieve this.

```
<select ng-options="option as option.name for option in timespanList | momentFilter" ng-model="currentOption"></select>

.filter('momentFilter',function(){
            return function (object) {
                var array = [];
                angular.forEach(object, function (time) {
                        if(time.startDate.split(" ")[1] == '06:00' && time.endDate.split(" ")[1] == '11:59'){
                          array.push(time);
                        }
                });
                return array;
            };
        });
```

I have created a working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ruwQ4L0YyA6WbjSQdG3J?p=preview).

Do little more work around to achieve this.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. I found a good solution for me, please look at my edited question. Perhaps there is something you also can use! Thansk again.

Comment: PS: I will mark your solution also as correct, because it can be used as a working alternative solution in case of the moment.js. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks..:) @MrBuggy

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION FROM THE QUESTION:**

I put my own solution which is in my edited question here so everyone can see it faster:

I've found a perfect way to solve this problem: I found moment.js, which solves my requirements. After including it into my web app I start to use the queries and functions from moment.js to solve my problem. It works like this:

Get current timestamp (day, month, year, hour and minutes):

```
let currentTimestamp = moment(); //for example 19.09.2016 11:30
```

Than I loop throught my array with the timespans and parse the startDate/endDate with the moment.js to my required format DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm and then I can use the moment.js query isBetween() to check, if my currentTimestamp is between the startDate/endDate of each item like this:

```
this.timespanList.forEach(function(item) {
    let startDate = moment(item.startDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'); // for example 19.09.2016 06:00
    let endDate= moment(item.endDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'); // for example 19.09.2016 11:59

    if(moment(currentTimestamp).isBetween(startDate, endDate)) {
        $scope.currentOption = item;
    }
});
```

So if the condition of the looped item is true, I can set the right option in my list. Here are some links of moment.js which describe, how to use it correcty - it's awesome!

moment.js docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/

moment.js parsing: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

moment.js queries: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

I hope this is usefull! An alternative solution from the answers which also would work is marked as correct. Thanks and cheers.